# Why garbage collection? Why not compilers auto-insert free() instead?

Tags: compiler-construction, garbage-collection

Rather than running garbage-detection periodically at run time, why don't we make compilers automatically insert free() at appropriate places? That way, we pay the price only once at compile-time.

The compiler knows the places where a variable goes out of scope or gets reassigned to different object. So, it can then find out if the object is no longer reachable, and insert free() automatically there.

Can't it? Why?

If it's because of multithreading, can we do it with single-threaded/green-threaded languages then?

Comment: You mean like C++ RAII?

Comment: You have guessed correctly. It can't. Generations of programmees and computer scientists are not, in fact, incompetent fools (a big surprise here). Now in order to see why, consider the simlest form of garbage collection, reference counting. Why run-time counting is needed? Can the compiler calculate the count statically? What information would it need to do so?

Comment: @n.m. I think it's possible on no-pointer-arithmetic languages. The fool is definitely on me, since I can't figure out the why.

Comment: You are thinking wrong. Read the questions again. Why do you need to count references? Can there be 2 references to the same object? 2000? More than the number of variables in the entire program? Assume there are no arrays.

Comment: You may want to take a look at the rust programming language. It tries to embed the concept of ownership and object reachability into its type system and that succeeds for a large part, but even there you cannot always do without reference counting.

Comment: @n.m. sure, on every `new()` give it a counter. Then, on assignments (works even with array) increment the corresponding counter. On reassignment, decrement the old target's counter and increment the new target's. It won't work with circular references, but that's refcounting's problem.

Comment: You have just described *how* a reference counter works. But *why* do you need one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The compiler knows the places where a variable goes out of scope or gets reassigned to different object.

Sure it does - for variables. But you do not clear variables - you clear the memory they are pointing to. And just because a variable went out of scope, it does not mean that the memory pointed to is no longer reachable.

For example:

```
y = ...
{
  x = new X();
  if (todayIsTuesday()) {
    y = x;
  }
} // x just went out of scope
```

You can't make a compile-time decision whether the memory pointed to by x should be freed at the last line of that segment, because it depends on what day of the week it is when that code is *ran*.

So to solve this, this decision must be delegated to run-time, by inserting proper logic, e.g.:

```
Y* y = ...
{
  X* mem = new X();
  X* x = mem;
  markPointer(&x, mem);
  if (todayIsTuesday()) {
    y = x;
    markPointer(&y, mem);
  }
  markNoLongerPointer(&x, mem);
} // x just went out of scope
```

With `markNoLongerPointer()` clearing the memory given as the 2nd argument if its internally-maintained data structure told it that `x` is the only reference to that memory... In other words, this is the crude starting point to a reference-counting logic.

Compilers certainly can add such reference-counting logic to the compiled code, and some do, but as others mentioned, reference counting has some disadvantages: high overhead, the problem of cycles, plus it can sometimes cause significant pauses at inconvenient times, when the only reference to a root of a large data structure goes out of scope. There are ways to address some of these disadvantages, though, but that's out of scope for this answer :-)

Comment: The cycles and the big root out of scope case is why e.g. Delphi doesn't do refcounting on container types (structs,classes).  It can still happen using interfaces, but those were mostly meant for interface external objects, not internal.  For normal classes it uses manual memory management.

Answer (score 1):

As you can read more about in this [Wikipedia article on Reference Counting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting#Advantages_and_disadvantages), there are two main disadvantages to reference counting over garbage collection:

1. *The overhead of maintaining the references*: From a performance point of view, this is pretty considerable. Each time any other object refers to another object or a reference goes out of scope, the JVM would need to increment and/or decrement the count. Also, it incurs more space, to maintain the reference counts; every object will consume at least an additional four byte integer.
2. *The problem of cyclical references:* This seems to be the biggest reason. Lots of meat and potatoes data structures used in Java have cyclical references. The first use case that comes to mind is nodes in a linked list. The issue gets more complicated for real world problems and more esoteric data structures.

Comment: i'm not sure if that is an answer to the question, considering that reference counting essentially is a restricted form of automatic garbage collection and not the same as freeing objects when they go out of local scope.

Comment: I'm not saying that the compiler must use reference counting to detect where an object becomes garbage. The compiler's writer is free to use any garbage-detection algorithm he/she wants.

Answer (score 1):

Just fundamentally, in non-trivial resource management cases, the programmer explicitly has to `free` memory (and other resources) anyway. It might not exactly resemble a call to `free`; it might be removing an object reference from a list so that a garbage collector can collect it, or setting it to a null reference, or releasing a smart pointer, or removing an object from a list, or a genuine call to `free`. However the programmer must still explicitly specify it some way, somehow, in non-trivial cases, to avoid logical leaks.

This cannot be determined at compile-time until we have compilers that can start reading our minds and figuring out what type of software we're making or until we start writing code in radically different ways. Because imagine, say, an image editor like Photoshop. When should it free an image? When the user closes it.  That's obvious to us humans but it's not information compilers have.

Similar case for a digital audio workstation. When should an audio clip be freed from memory? When the user removes it from the clip editor, e.g. Again that's something obvious to human designers but not to compilers. When should my 80s music collection be deleted from my hard drive to save space? When I, the user, explicitly delete them. It can't get any less manual/explicit than that until the software can start reliably reading my mind.

So there's no automated resource management whether you have garbage collection or RAII or anything else for these non-trivial cases. The programmer must always explicitly `free` resources in such cases in response to the proper inputs/events regardless because it's human ideas and designs very specific to the domain of the application that determine when those resources should be freed.

Of course for trivial cases like memory allocated local to a given scope of a function, the compiler can automatically free it without anything hefty like garbage collection, and they do. Even in C:

```
void some_func(...)
{
     int some_array[64];
     ...
     // some_array's memory will be automatically freed from 
     // the stack when exiting the function.
}
```

... and there C is basically doing the analogical equivalent of what you're suggesting. It'll generate instructions to increment/decrement the stack pointer, e.g., to effectively allocate and free memory and make the freed memory available for use elsewhere. With C++, it can even do that for heap-allocated memory when using RAII, provided that the object that owns that memory becomes unreachable when exiting the function's scope. But these types of temporary resources whose lifetimes are tied to the scope of a function with stack-like allocation/deallocation push/pop patterns are the trivial cases. The non-trivial cases will always require the programmer to explicitly specify when a resource is no longer needed some way, somehow, because the non-trivial cases deal with persistent state whose lifetime is not tied to the scope of any given function.